# C# Running Batch File and Capturing Response

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am currently writing an application that needs to user a 3rd party encryption key generator. The tool is a batch file that in turn runs a Java executable. The batch file accepts a couple of parameters, I am currently using -e

**Here is my current method code:**

```
private string EncryptedPassword(string unencrypted)
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\encrypt2.bat";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = " –e " + unencrypted;
            string returned = null;
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => returned = args.Data;
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return returned;
        }
```

**The problem I keep getting is:**

```
'process.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    int {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong?**
I think it could be a file system permissions error, in which case can this be resolved using a parameter on the process?

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: batch file is not a process. add "cmd.exe /c" + path to the file

Comment: @PraveenPaulose - process.Start(); throws the exception

Comment: Or set `UseShellExecute = true`. And print out `Exception.Message` - might give you more information about the error!

Comment: @OldFox - Prefixing this to the FileName results in "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: @MatthewWatson The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.

Comment: Do you have to execute the batch file?  Can you execute the java executable directly?  Also, try setting the `WorkingDirectory` property and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a full sample. Note that priority can be set only after you start the process. I recommend noting the details such as setting UTF-8 encoding of the child process. Note that in this example I assume you really want to wait until the process finishes, if that is not the case, your handling has to look little different, but that is another question ...

```
public class ProcessContainer
{
  private Process process;
  private List<string> processOutput = new List<string>();

  public List<string> RunProcessGrabOutput(string Executable, string Arguments)
  {
    try
    {
      process = new Process();
      process.StartInfo.FileName = Executable;
      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Executable);
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Arguments))
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;

      process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputHandler);
      process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputHandler);
      process.Start();

      process.BeginOutputReadLine();
      process.BeginErrorReadLine();

      // You can set the priority only AFTER the you started the process.
      process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
      process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch
    {
      // This is how we indicate that something went wrong.
      processOutput = null;
    }

    return processOutput;
  }

  private void ProcessOutputHandler(object SendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs OutLine)
  {
    processOutput.Add(OutLine.Data + Environment.NewLine);
  }
}
```

Then this code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ProcessContainer proc = new ProcessContainer();
  List<string> output = proc.RunProcessGrabOutput("ping.exe", "-n 5 8.8.8.8");
  if (output != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Program's output:");
    foreach (string line in output)
      Console.Write(">> " + line);
  }
  else Console.WriteLine("Unable to start program.");
}
```

Produces output like this:

```
Program's output:
>>
>> Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
>> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=54
>> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
>> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
>> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
>> Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
>>
>> Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
>>     Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 5, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>>     Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 23ms
>>
>>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly! Exactly what I wanted after I modified the output format. Thank you very much!